# There is static when I export video where there is none in editing (premiere pro)

Tags: audio, editing, noise, noise-reduction

The problem is that when I export the video, there is static in the beginning of each clip, which goes away after a little while. It's very prominent when there are a lot of quick cuts. In the longer clips there is static in the first 5 seconds or so and then it sounds fine. The worst part is that I can only sometimes hear this in Premiere Pro, mostly the audio sounds perfectly fine start to finish, but it's there every time I export the video. I've been using the youtube exporting preset. I've also tried .avi file and it's there, too.

The mic we used in the shoot was a Sennheiser MKE400, and the sound was quiet and there was a lot of static, so I had to use compression and denoiser effects.

Please help! Here is a short sample of the video:

Comment: What player are you using to watch the exported video? A short sample would be useful.

Comment: I'm using windows media player to test, and the static still shows up when I uploaded to youtube.

Comment: What audio hardware is selected in Premier (and what options do you have) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by audio hardware, do you mean the speakers I'm using to listen to the audio? Or the mic used to record the sound? If it's the former, Premiere pro wdm sound seems to be the only option. If it's the latter, I don't know how to set that.

Comment: I chose the preset for the Canon t4i when I opened the project. The t4i has a built in mic, but I was using the Sennheiser. So I'm thinking maybe they have different settings and that's why I'm getting this issue? Different sample rate? I tried to find out the sample rate of the Sennheiser, but couldn't. The project is set to 4800 Hz

Comment: Audio compression usually adds to background noise. What a compressor does is to make the loud stuff quiet and the quiet stuff loud – so if you have someone talking with stretches of silence it will bring up all the background noise during the silence. If you have background noise or hiss on your material you should avoid using it. Listening to the clip it sounds awfully like the hiss is on one of your audio tracks. It starts and stops quite cleanly, as if it has been edited. Could it be that it's coming off the interviewer's mic? Try soloing tracks and cranking your speakers in the edit suite

Comment: I got same issue. Even though the audio has been edited and on the preview seems to be perfectly fine, once the file is exported each clip begins with two-three second hiss noise ;/ it seems like a compression issue...

Answer (score 2):

I realize this comes a bit late, but what the heck....

I've run into this same phenomenon. What's happening is a natural result of using the Denoiser audio plug-in in Adobe Premiere. Unfortunately, it takes about 4 seconds for Premiere to "learn" the noise print of a clip. That is why you're hearing about 4 seconds of static and unwanted background noise before it suddenly sounds a lot cleaner when the effect finally applies itself.

As for the second half of your question, the reason that you're not hearing that unwanted background noise at the beginning of the clip while editing in Adobe Premiere is the result of caching. Adobe Premiere often caches audio and video effects in either the RAM or graphics card (depending on the effect). As such, when you play your timeline in Premiere, you won't hear the Denoiser plugin "learning" the noise print for the first four seconds of your clips since the noise print has already been cached inside of Premiere. Why this isn't the case when you export the final timeline is beyond me. All I know is that for now, Adobe feels fit to have its exporter in Premiere and Adobe Media Encoder treat each clip individually during export. This means that the Denoiser effect needs to "relearn" the noise print for each instance in each clip, resulting in background noise for the first four seconds of every clip.

I for one hope that Adobe fixes it and that this answer somehow helps.  - Dan

Comment: The freeze option should help as long as it is consistent noise.

Answer (score -1):

render the whole audiotracktogether as audio file, import the rendered audio file in timeline, and then apply the denoiser to that.

To me it worked perfectly on an interview with a lot of background noise. Just kept all the other effects on, saved the denoiser i used as a preset and then i took it off, rendered in .aac, and then applied the denoiser preset to the .aac file.